# How can i achieve Figma shadow-like effects in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, figma

So i am trying to create a button like this :
[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts0Pm.png)
that has these drop shadow options :
offset y axis : 8
offset x axis : 0
blur : 12
color : (0,0,0,0.05)
[Figma shadow options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOB1d.png)

Here's what i achieved so far in xml :
[Button in XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfbJK.png)

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:background="@color/neutralwhite"
        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menuicon" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Pretty close but not quite, So my question is : Is there another way i can achieve those shadow properties from figma in android ?